# Eclipse/maven - "Cannot change version of project facet EAR to 6.0

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, ear

My Eclipse project has the following problem:

Maven error:

> |Description||Resource||Path||Location||Type |Cannot change version of
>   project facet EAR to 6.0.|[name]-ear||line 1|Maven Java EE
>   Configuration Problem

Answer (score 12):

I edited the fellowing files:

File: pom.xml:

```
[...]
<dependencies>
 [...]
 <dependency>
  <groupId>javax</groupId>
  <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
  <version>6.0</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
 </dependency>
 [...]
</dependencies>
[...]
```

File: org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.xml

```
[...]
<faceted-project>
 <installed facet="jst.ear" version="6.0"/>
</faceted-project>
[...]
```

after  > `Maven` > `Update maven Project`

Comment: Thanks. FWIW I tried doing just the second step (there being no existing such dependency in my pom.xml), followed by Maven -> Update Project..  and it worked.